# Indesign always exports previous version of document

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

So there's this weird thing happening:
I exported a file to PDF with InDesign, then a few days later made some changes to the InDesign file and tried to export again.

Yet, when I check the 'new' PDF, it's identical to the previous version! As if I hadn't made any changes.

I've saved the InDesign file, duplicated it, renamed it, exported to PDF with different titles, tried to export with different resolutions, restarted InDesign, restarted my computer, made sure InDesign was updated to the latest version... and yet **it constantly exports the file as if no changes had been made**.

It never did that before.

Comment: Sounds like you are exporting to another place and you are looking at the same file over and over.

Answer (score 0):

It just happened to me today. Just export to idml and resave it again. Then after that, try to export to pdf. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

GO to your library - Put your Cache in the trash.
Empty your Cookie folder
Restart
and empty your trash.

Works for several indesign problems.